# Compaq Presario CQ70

Tags: windows-7

I have a Compaq Presario CQ70 2009 model. We got a virus so had to have new Windows 7 put onto it, so we lost everything. So now we cant' use the Scroller up and down on the tracker pad. How do i get it to work again Please?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the Official website of Compaq and search for the trackpad(mousepad) drivers for your laptop.
2. Or if you have the drivers CD (that are given when you Buy the laptop),you can take the drivers from there.
   Good Luck !!

Comment: Please Mark this as answer, if you found so .Thank you.